# A gold reviewer badge?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, badge-request

For your continued efforts in reviewing posts, even though the system sometimes messes up and doesn't let you actually review things and keeps displaying them over and over and over. So also, for your patience in putting up with the glitches in the review panel too! Haha

**Anyways, a gold reviewer badge: 20000 reviews, over 4000 actioned**

I just multiplied both numbers by 20. Think those numbers seem challenging? Is anyone up near those numbers or should it be multiplied by 10 instead? I prefer the higher amount because it would be gold and something harder to work for. :) But we also have to consider the longevity of when all these posts *are* eventually reviewed and it's only new posts being created.

Anyways, my stats for those who are interested (I wouldn't get the badge to start because I only have ~2000 actioned):

```
Upvoted            189
Downvoted          11
Edited             926
Commented          127
Voted to Close     44
Flagged            447
Reviewed           21609
```

As far as the name of the badge, I really like "The Owl is Watching" but not sure if that would be too long. Sounds snazzy though. Ideas?

---

Personally, I *was* on a quest to try and clear out all the posts in a single tab before it started showing me the same things over and over (and over) and then it got frustrating because I wasn't even making progress. Quest denied. :(

---

Lately I've noticed a massive build-up of unreviewed posts. When the review panel was first implemented, there would only ever be maybe 50 unreviewed posts at a time (in a given tab) for my monthly view. Now I log in and there's a thousand or two thousand pending. I think a lot of people quit reviewing after the first badge, so having a gold badge with a high threshold would really improve activity in the review panel and keep people going to improve the community.

Comment: I believe you need two reviewers (qualified enough) to close an item.

Comment: I don't think its a bad idea but you may want to include a reason for why you think adding a gold version would add value rather than just then just explaining the requirements for it. After all there are several badges that don't have a gold version and there's probably some thinking behind that.

Comment: Do people really put more effort into [any SE activity] just to get a small yellow dot, or larger number, next to their name? Cuz if they're doing it just for the badges... that's a bit sad.

Comment: @IgbyLargeman What, exactly, do you think the point of the badges is then?  They are there to encourage good behavior.  People like collecting shiny things =)

Comment: @jadarnel27: I guess that is the point of badges. And I guess it probably works for some people. Hey, if collecting little dots on a website is their hobby... whatever makes them happy!

Comment: @IgbyLargeman do you think its different than going after Achievements in video games?

Comment: @ConradFrix: if you're *only* playing the game for the acheivements, then it's the same. If you would have played anyway because it's fun, then yes it's different.

Comment: Name suggestions: `Quality Control` `Valiant Knight` (I'm thinking something like Reddit's self-proclaimed "Knights of New" on that one) and `Defender`

Comment: More name suggestions: Examiner, Auditor, Inspector, Assessor, Reflector, Reporter, Scanner

Comment: How new review stats going to be displayed according to new review system :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This has been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) for the new review queues.

The requirements are somewhat lower than what you suggest - 1,000 vs. 4,000 actioned reviews - but since the new badges are *per-queue* they should be somewhat more challenging: you can't combine actions in different queues to hit a badge. Naturally, badges for some queues will be easier to achieve than others.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with you, although we might disagree on the number of edits required.

I know I'll sound like a badge whore for writing this, but **1,000** reviews just for a *silver* badge? Not just looking at 1,000 questions/answers, mind you, but actually making executive decisions on *1,000 discrete posts*.

Depending on your area of expertise, this may involve skipping hundreds of posts for which you would click "Not Sure" (in the new Beta interface). I don't know about you, but if I see something I don't understand, I won't click "Recommend Deletion" or "Looks Okay" just to get closer to a badge.

The low quality queue on Stack Overflow is huge right now (60k+), there should be some further incentive to continue editing after achieving Reviewer.

Comment: Given the time and effort required to actually hit 1,000 reviews, this did seem like a fair number. The folks who dug through the huge Low Quality backlog certainly deserve it.