# Additional Info in Profile Stats

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, information-display

I have under 2k reputation on Stackoverflow so not sure if my feature request already exists for those with higher reputation.

I have noticed that the only way to view your Review Progress is by clicking "review" on the top menu, then going to 1 of the 3 links in the "Review Lists (old)" section.

Would it not be a good idea to add `Number of Reviews` and `Number of Edits` to the profile pages under `Helpful Flags`?

Please share your opinions.

Comment: `I have under 2k reputation on Stackoverflow so not sure if my feature request already exists for those with higher reputation.` No, it doesn't.

Comment: The old review system was nice in that just clicking "review" showed you this. Perhaps it could be moved to the new review page?

Comment: On a more relevant note, I do like the idea of showing these along with Helpful Flags. Unfortunately, I've voted too much today, so no upvote for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most user-specific stats are specifically designed to only be visible to that user, including your helpful flags count. Only website, location, age, member for, seen, and profile views are visible to the public. Your email, real name, visited stats, and helpful flags are **not** shown to other users.

I really don't see any need to add number of reviews to the profile page, as that's not really a helpful number to anyone viewing your profile. The only place I can see it being of any real use is in an election. The SE team has also [made no indication yet that those review stats will even be carried over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141279) to the new review panel, but have confirmed that there will be some sort of stats summary for the entire new review panel at some point, and that the existing badge progress indicators will be integrated into the panel.

Anyone can already see the number of revisions you've made simply by viewing your [activity history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1362108/lodder?tab=activity&sort=revisions).