# Comment upvote should be considered as an action for review

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, review

While reviewing, the following user activities are currently considered to be *action* on a post:

- Upvoted
- Downvoted
- Edited
- Commented
- Voted to Close
- Flagged
- Deleted
- Reviewed

But, there is one more activity that a reviewer can perform, and it is **upvote a comment**, as there might be a comment already present, giving the same message that the current reviewer has.

This should be considered, as I have found myself in such condition several times.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Comments are not that important that upvoting one should be considered an action while reviewing. As well, those stats [may or may not become obsolete](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141279) when the rest of the old review tasks gets replaced by the new system.

Comment: Closing this as a duplicate, even though this is in relation to the old review system and the one I linked to is in relation to the new one, since for all intents and purposes the old system is now dead - none of these actions are tracked anymore outside of the new queues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I agree with @mtk.  Often when reviewing a post, I see that it has been commented previously by a different reviewer, and the comment addresses the required issue. At this point, my contribution is to upvote that comment to reinforce the point it's making, but I can't upvote comments in the review page, so I have to click the link to get to the actual thread and then upvote the comment.  This is tedious, and gets in the way of reviewing the posts effectively.