# What counts as 'completing a review task' in the new system?

Tags: support, badges, review

Following on the [New Community Review badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147912/new-community-review-badges) question, what is 'completing a review task'?  Does it mean what used to be 'reviewed', or what used to be 'actioned'? IE, do you have to do something & then click "I'm done"? What happens if you click "not sure"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have to do something that enables the "I'm Done" button and then click it.

Clicking "Not Sure" doesn't count as a review action.

Comment: +1, thanks for your prompt response, @ChrisF. FWIW, I think it's possible to have legitimately put in some effort on a post, but still have nothing but the "Not Sure" button available. EG, I've looked at posts that have already been commented on appropriately regarding their issues, & not thought it merited either an upvote or a downvote (at least until the OP has had adequate time) & so my only action is to click the link to navigate over to the post to upvote the comment to reinforce the point. But I recognize the difficulty in assessing this type of situation.

Comment: @gung - voting on a comment counts as an action, so you always use that.

Comment: you can't vote on comments from the review page, you have to navigate over to the page in question's regular location. I think this is a bug, but [I gather](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146282/comment-upvote-should-be-considered-as-an-action-for-review) the powers-that-be think this is a feature.

Comment: @gung - Oh. I'm sure you could. Maybe it's only on some queues.

Comment: @gung: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146998/new-first-post-review-queue-upvoted-comment-should-be-a-valid-action - the request you linked to was in relation to the old review system. Comment votes really only make sense as "actions" in some contexts - the new system allows this where sane.

Comment: @Shog9, thanks for the tip. FWIW, I certainly didn't realize that the initial post was only focused on the old system, is that because mtk used the 'review' tag, instead of the 'review-beta' tag? It's ironic to me that what seems like the same question goes from -5 to +12, but I'm glad the situation may be resolved.

Comment: @gung: it focused on the old review system since that's what he was using and what he described in the question - when he posted it, the First Post and Late Answer queues hadn't been added yet, so there was no equivalent "grabbag of review actions" available in the new system.