# closed as duplicate - please clarify on this concerned post

Tags: discussion, voting, duplicate-questions, meta

I had asked a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146282/comment-upvote-should-be-considered-as-an-action-for-review) regarding 'Considering upvote a comment as a action in review' on Sep 7. It was later closed as exact duplicate to [another question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146998/new-first-post-review-queue-upvoted-comment-should-be-a-valid-action) which was posted by a moderator on Sep 14.

So, I would like to know, how could a older post be a duplicate of a post asked 7 days after it. I guess it should have been the other way round. or atleast the moderators closing it should have checked this.

Other thing that concern's me is the voter/down-voters thinking over here. [No offence with any one], but my post stands with a total of -2 (+5/-7) and the later one stand with +18(+18/ 0 -ve). I don't think the viewers to this question were totally a different group of people.

Please, give your views about this.

Comment: about the voting: people who agreed with you probably refrained from voting because they had already voted on the dupe and didn't want to encourage dupe-posting. People who disagreed probably felt there was no problem disagreeing twice.

Comment: Dupe closing is not restricted to newer posts only. Generally older posts are favoured to be kept open at the expense of the newer post, but that is not a rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shog9 explains why it was closed [in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146282/comment-upvote-should-be-considered-as-an-action-for-review#comment425263_146282):

> Closing this as a duplicate, even though this is in relation to the old review system and the one I linked to is in relation to the new one, since for all intents and purposes the old system is now dead - none of these actions are tracked anymore outside of the new queues.

To respond to the more general question of why a old question could be closed in favor of a newer question, there are a lot of possible reasons:

**Better formulated**: A question that is written well and easy on the eyes is more likely to get good answers and more likely to withstand scrutiny, even if it's newer.

**More views**: Google matters. Pageviews matter.  I will close questions as duplicates in favor of the question with more views because it increases the likelihood that question is used in hyperlinks throughout the internet (and there are other reasons, but this is just one)

**Better answers**: In this case, Thiefmaster's question had an answer from a Stack Exchange developer, making it canonical

**More relevant**:  Sometimes, the way a question is asked can determine whether it will be superseded by another question. This happened in your case: The feature changed, and so your question lost some of its relevance that the other question retained.